# Is there accepted notation and/or terminology for the smallest cover of $S$ with cells from $P$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology, order-theory

Let $X$ denote a set. Then for $S \subseteq X$ and $P$ a partitioning of $X$, define $P \diamond S$ as the smallest cover of $S$ with cells from $P$. Explicitly:

$$P \diamond S = \bigcup\{Q \in P \mid Q\cap S \ne \emptyset\}$$

So $P \diamond S$ is kind of like a blurred-out version of $S$.

> **Question.** Is there accepted notation and/or terminology for the operation $\diamond$?

**Motivation.** Consider a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$. We obtain two corresponding functions $f_\mathrm{ker}$ and $f_\mathrm{im}$ as follows.

$$f_\mathrm{ker} : \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X) \qquad f_\mathrm{im} : \mathcal{P}(Y) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(Y)$$

$$f_\mathrm{ker}(A) = f^{-1}(f(A)) \qquad f_\mathrm{im}(B) = f(f^{-1}(B))$$

Now let $\mathrm{im}(f)$ denote the image of $f$. Then the latter map has a rather simple description:

$$f_\mathrm{im}(B) = \mathrm{im}(f) \cap B$$

Let us furthermore write $\mathrm{ker}(f)$ for the partitioning induced on $X$ by $f$. Then:

$$f_\mathrm{ker}(A) = \mathrm{ker}(f) \diamond A$$

Comment: Just to be clear, $P \diamond S$ is the smallest cover of $S$ with sets from $P$, right?
$$P \diamond S = \bigcup_{Q\in P, Q\cap S \ne \emptyset} Q$$

Comment: @AlexR, yeah, that's a much better way of explaining it.

Comment: I wrote down an equivalent formula for it in an edit to emphasize that.

Comment: @AlexR, I shamelessly plagiarized it. :)

Comment: You're welcome ;) $\ker(f)$ is then
$$\ker(f) = \{ Q_\alpha = \{ x \in X | f(x) = \alpha\} | \alpha\in Y \}$$

Comment: Since$ P$ is a partition we can define the equivalence relation $P^*$ by $x P^* y \iff \exists p\in P\;(x,y\in p).$  With the usual notation, $P=\{[x]_{P^*} :x\in X\}=X/P^*$ and $P\diamond S=\cup \{[x]_{P^*} :x\in S\}.$

Answer (score 0):

On page (2) of [this](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869387900949/1-s2.0-0021869387900949-main.pdf?_tid=d7821a4e-7dd6-11e7-aeb0-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1502374915_3a57355650e0cfcdf57e8ed552e2b646) article, they essentially make the following definition:

> **Definition.** If $X$ is a set, $S$ is a subset thereof, and $R$ is a equivalence relation on $X$, then:
>
> $$S/R = \{y \in X : \exists x \in S(xRy)\}$$

So basically, what I'm denoting $R \diamond S$ can be denoted $S/R$, as long as we don't worry too much about the distinction between partitions and equivalence relations.